# actualizar campos en una matriz de objetos Mongoodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

necesito hacer update a un documento que se llama 'storage' que se encuentra en una array de objetos,sin embargo dentro del documento storage tengo una array de objetos llamado client, que no quiero modificar. sin embargo al hacer el update se actualiza todo el documento de 'storage'. borrando lo que tengo en 'client'.
alguien sabe alguna solución?

estructura del documento

```
   rut: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    name: String,
    address: {
        name: String,
        region: String,
        commune: String,
    },
    phone: String,
    type: Boolean,
    status: Boolean,
    storage: [{
        code: String,  //4-6  required
        name: String,  //4-255 required 
        address: {
            name: String,     //4-255  required
            region: String,   //required
            commune: String,  //required
        },
        status: Boolean,  //required
        equipment: [{
            type: shema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'equipments'
        }],
        requests: [{
            type: shema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'requests'
        }],
        technicals: [{
            _id: {
                type: shema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'employees'
            }
        }],
        client: [{
            rut: String,
            name: String,
            pLastName: String,
            mLastName: String,
            email: String,
            phone: [{
                type: Number
            }],
            password: String,
            role: {
                type: shema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'roles',
            },
            status: Boolean
        }]
    }]
```

funcion de actualizacion:
tengo la idea de que el problema puede ser el arrayFilter, sin embargo no encuentro otra manera eficiente de poder hacer una actualizacion.

```
function updateStorage(_idCompany, _idStorage, storage) { //funcion que agrega un objeto de bodega nuevo al _id empresa asociado
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {          
             
            await model.update({'_id': _idCompany},{'storage.$[stor]':storage},{arrayFilters: [{ "stor._id": { $eq: _idStorage } }]})
                .then(dataResult=>{
                    resolve(dataResult)
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    reject(boom.conflict('there was a conflict', err.message))
                })
        } catch (err) {
            reject(boom.expectationFailed('expected this to work', err.message));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hola Marias, lo que buscas es sustituir todos los campos del subdocumento `storage` sin sustituir el campo `client`, correcto?

Comment: exacto ese es mi problema

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se me ocurre es solo actualizar los campos que necesitas, dejando el campo `client` sin actualizar, de esa forma se actualizaría todos los campos que necesites.

```
 model.update(
           { '_id': _idCompany}, // Filter document
           { $set: { // Update fields
                 'storage.$[stor].code': storage.code,
                 'storage.$[stor].name': storage.name,
                 'storage.$[stor].address': storage.address,
                 'storage.$[stor].status': storage.status,
                 'storage.$[stor].equipment': storage.equipment,
                 'storage.$[stor].requests': storage.requests,
                 'storage.$[stor].technicals': storage.technicals
            }},
            { arrayFilters: [{ "stor._id": { $eq: _idStorage } }]} // Filter subdocument
       )
```

Hay otra forma de poder realizarlo, con la version de MongoDB 4.2 se ha añadido la funcionalidad de realizar `pipeline` en el método `update`. Entonces con esto lo que se me ocurre es utilizar el operador `$mergeObjects` para fusionar los objetos, tendiendo en cuenta de que objeto `storage` se le debería eliminar la propiedad `client`para que la fusion de objetos no afectara. (Esto no lo he probado pero pienso que iría bien).

Espero que esta respuesta pueda ayudarte a tu problema.

Cualquier cosa avisa.

Un saludo